# Build a directory tree from an object

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

Having an array of items with the following format:

```
[ { path: '/Folder 1/Folder 1.1',
    name: 'Folder 1.1.1',
    id: 'Fi6CsP4RWFutOZKsIDoYMSfBPQb-A-lj3C4Jc_zZoG0' },
  { path: '/Folder 1',
    name: 'Folder 1.2',
    id: 'c2dTN3CgBr9Xik8jdpBkfzR6wZ00oGTX3IbfXrfFujM' },
  { path: '/Folder 1',
    name: 'Folder 1.1',
    id: 'WmKaOZhzpubcunNNoxbUnqfSYVuNQZDNC852KDJK_G8' },
  { path: '/',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    id: 'aNRvIvCLyNOgLOmZVzFhoOiZMAz3-p87kBFIGSQS2Yg' },
  { path: '/',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    id: 'S4FkkQ3hgLTVedIrlSBqe2_1DhrrnLx5szk7-9Wv3X8' } ]
```

It is possible to take it to a format like the following

```
var dir = {
"directory": [{
        "text": "Folder 1",
        "id": 'aNRvIvCLyNOgLOmZVzFhoOiZMAz3-p87kBFIGSQS2Yg',
        "nodes": [{
            "text": "Folder 1.1",
            "id": 'WmKaOZhzpubcunNNoxbUnqfSYVuNQZDNC852KDJK_G8',
            "nodes": [{
                "text": "Folder 1.1.1",
                "id": 'Fi6CsP4RWFutOZKsIDoYMSfBPQb-A-lj3C4Jc_zZoG0'
            }]
            }, {
            "text": "Folder 1.2",
            "id": 'c2dTN3CgBr9Xik8jdpBkfzR6wZ00oGTX3IbfXrfFujM'
        }]
    },
    {
        "text": "Folder 2",
        "id": 'S4FkkQ3hgLTVedIrlSBqe2_1DhrrnLx5szk7-9Wv3X8'
    }
]
};
```

Graphically
[Tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLmO8.png)

I was thinking using recursion, but I still have not been able to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a non-recursive solution that works by first building a tree, then transforming the tree into the desired structure.

The reason for the first step is due to the slowness of iterating over `node` arrays in linear time and assumes no order of the flat input array. Performing lookups on an object tree structure speeds up and simplifies the process, making the result tree easy to build in a single traversal.

```js
const treeify = data => 
  data.reduce((a, e) => {
    let level = a;
    
    e.path.split("/")
      .filter(e => e)
      .forEach(dir => {
        if (!(dir in level)) {
          level[dir] = {nodes: {}};
        }

        level = level[dir].nodes;
      })
    ;
    
    if (e.name in level) {
      level[e.name] = {
        text: e.name,
        id: e.id, 
        nodes: level[e.name].nodes
      };
    }
    else {
      level[e.name] = {text: e.name, id: e.id};
    }
    
    return a;
  }, {})
;

const format = tree => {
  const result = [];
  const stack = [[result, tree]];
  
  while (stack.length) {
    const [res, curr] = stack.pop();
    
    for (const k in curr) {
      const o = {
        id: curr[k].id,
        text: curr[k].text
      };
      res.push(o);
      
      if (curr[k].nodes) {
        o.nodes = [];
        stack.push([o.nodes, curr[k].nodes]);
      }
    }
  }
  
  return {directory: result};
};

const data = [
  {
    path: '/Folder 1/Folder 1.1',
    name: 'Folder 1.1.1',
    id: 'Fi6CsP4RWFutOZKsIDoYMSfBPQb-A-lj3C4Jc_zZoG0'
  },
  {
    path: '/Folder 1',
    name: 'Folder 1.2',
    id: 'c2dTN3CgBr9Xik8jdpBkfzR6wZ00oGTX3IbfXrfFujM'
  },
  {
    path: '/Folder 1',
    name: 'Folder 1.1',
    id: 'WmKaOZhzpubcunNNoxbUnqfSYVuNQZDNC852KDJK_G8'
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Folder 1',
    id: 'aNRvIvCLyNOgLOmZVzFhoOiZMAz3-p87kBFIGSQS2Yg'
  },
  {
    path: '/',
    name: 'Folder 2',
    id: 'S4FkkQ3hgLTVedIrlSBqe2_1DhrrnLx5szk7-9Wv3X8'
  }
];

console.log(format(treeify(data)));
```

Comment: What happens if the folders do not have a number? The folders name would be "myfolder" or anything else

Comment: Whoops, I only worked on the provided dataset. Feel free to update your question with accurate i/o and I can adjust for that.

Comment: I'm thinking you want to rely on `/` in the `path` key to determine the nesting?

Comment: Exactly, that way the folders are nested. 
That's why I was thinking about recursive way. But if there is some iterative form better

Comment: It shouldn't matter either way. I prefer iterative because it's faster and there's no potential stack overflow. I'll update the answer. Apologies for the miscommunication.

Comment: Updated. Let me know if there are any issues with this version.